# Set background image of parent div based on attribute of child div on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

For some reason this doesn't want to work for me. I've got the below code.

When hovering over the `homeShowingWrapper` div, the background of the `homeHero` div should change to the value of the `data-featured-image` attribute of the `homeShowingWrapper` div.

Here's my HTML structure:

```
<div id="homeHero">
    <div class="homeShowingWrapper" data-featured-image="/uploads/Hover-Background.jpg">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JQuery function:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    $("#homeHero").css("background-image" , "url(/uploads/Initial-Background.jpg);");

    $(".homeShowingWrapper").mouseover(function() {

        // Background-image
        var background = $(this).attr('data-featured-image');

        $("#homeHero").css("background-image" , "url(" + background + ");");

    });

});
```

Any idea why the `$("#homeHero").css("background-image" , "url(" + background + ");");` line doesn't apply the background image?

Comment: do a console.log(background) to find out if you are getting the data correctly. A jQuery way of reading data attribute is to var background = $(this).data('featured-image');

Comment: Yep, was getting the right URL. Answer below solved issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nawed Khan mentioned in the comments, the correct way of reading the data attribute is with `data()`.

[I set up a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gz9utcx/) to troubleshoot and found that, not only did I need to use `data('featured-image')`, but the semi-colon in the jQuery `.css()` needs to be omitted  for it to work.